# ElasticSearch/Tire only returning results for one index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, elasticsearch, tire

Right now I have the following code:

```
search = Tire.search ['object1_index', 'object2_index'] do |search|
  search.query { string params[:q] }
end

@results = search.results
```

The results right now are all coming from just object1, however, if I remove 'object1_index' with the same query, I do get object2 results. How can I get my search to interact with both indices at once?

edit:

I now have the following (using the search I have defined on my models), but as I will be eventually adding pagination I'm unsure if this is the best work around:

```
object1_results = Object1.search(params).results
object2_results = Object2.search(params).results
@results = object1_results + object2_results
@results.sort!(&:_score)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `size` parameter since **elasticsearch** default size is 10 which must be only limiting to `object1_index` search space in your case

```
search = Tire.search ['object1_index', 'object2_index'], size: 1000 do |search|
...
```

**Update**

For pagination, you can add `from` parameter